# Add/remove class while traversing through list-items

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, traversal

I don't quite understand why this isn't working.  I'm trying to make it so [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) click will [removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) `.active-title` from a list-item; Then [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) `.active-title` to the [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) list-item.

```
$(".next").on({
    click: function(){
        $('.active-title').removeClass(function(){
          $(this).next().addClass('active-title');
    }
  });
});
```

### *Demo:*

**[Link to JSFiddles Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDp/2/)**

---

### [Final Solution Demo in JSFIDDLES](http://jsfiddle.net/ujTDp/6/)

Comment: Click the "JSHint" button in JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your code

```
      }
   });
});
```

supposed to be

```
      }); <--- closing of removeClass
   } <-- closing for click function
});
```

---

Try this

```
$(".next").on({
    click: function () {
       // Find the actuve element
        var $active = $('.active-title', 'ul');
       // If the next element exists the get the element
       // otherwise get the first li from the ul
        var $nextElem = $active.next('li').length ? $active.next('li') 
                                                  : $('ul').find('li:first');
        // Add and remove class
        $active.removeClass('active-title');
        $nextElem.addClass('active-title');

    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/ujTDp/3/)**